# WSO2 IS PostAuthnMissingClaimHandler is not working

Tags: java, authentication, wso2, wso2-identity-server

I'm using wso2 identity server. I created a service provider and I configured it. (Inbound authentication configuration / OAuth/OpenId connect conf / Callback Url = http://localhost:8080/login / Token Issuer = JWT). It's work fine!

I added mandatory claim (eg. phoneNumbers). I clicked "sign in" on Provide Mandatory Details page and I get following exception:

```
TID: [-1234] [] [2019-10-15 09:13:54,774] DEBUG {org.wso2.carbon.identity.application.authentication.framework.services.PostAuthenticationMgtService} -  Post authentication handler PostAuthnMissingChallengeQuestionsHandler returned with status : SUCCESS_COMPLETED for context identifier : a87394cd-1fc8-4815-89bb-3660da92429f 
TID: [-1234] [] [2019-10-15 09:13:54,774] DEBUG {org.wso2.carbon.identity.application.authentication.framework.services.PostAuthenticationMgtService} -  Post authentication handler PostAuthnMissingChallengeQuestionsHandler completed execution for session context : a87394cd-1fc8-4815-89bb-3660da92429f 
TID: [-1234] [] [2019-10-15 09:13:54,774] DEBUG {org.wso2.carbon.identity.application.authentication.framework.services.PostAuthenticationMgtService} -  JITProvisionHandler is enabled. Hence executing for context : a87394cd-1fc8-4815-89bb-3660da92429f 
TID: [-1234] [] [2019-10-15 09:13:54,774] DEBUG {org.wso2.carbon.identity.application.authentication.framework.handler.request.impl.JITProvisioningPostAuthenticationHandler} -  Continuing with JIT flow for the user: admin@carbon.super 
TID: [-1234] [] [2019-10-15 09:13:54,774] DEBUG {org.wso2.carbon.identity.application.authentication.framework.services.PostAuthenticationMgtService} -  Post authentication handler JITProvisionHandler returned with status : SUCCESS_COMPLETED for context identifier : a87394cd-1fc8-4815-89bb-3660da92429f 
TID: [-1234] [] [2019-10-15 09:13:54,775] DEBUG {org.wso2.carbon.identity.application.authentication.framework.services.PostAuthenticationMgtService} -  Post authentication handler JITProvisionHandler completed execution for session context : a87394cd-1fc8-4815-89bb-3660da92429f 
TID: [-1234] [] [2019-10-15 09:13:54,775] DEBUG {org.wso2.carbon.identity.application.authentication.framework.services.PostAuthenticationMgtService} -  PostAuthAssociationHandler is enabled. Hence executing for context : a87394cd-1fc8-4815-89bb-3660da92429f 
TID: [-1234] [] [2019-10-15 09:13:54,775] DEBUG {org.wso2.carbon.identity.application.authentication.framework.services.PostAuthenticationMgtService} -  Post authentication handler PostAuthAssociationHandler returned with status : SUCCESS_COMPLETED for context identifier : a87394cd-1fc8-4815-89bb-3660da92429f 
TID: [-1234] [] [2019-10-15 09:13:54,775] DEBUG {org.wso2.carbon.identity.application.authentication.framework.services.PostAuthenticationMgtService} -  Post authentication handler PostAuthAssociationHandler completed execution for session context : a87394cd-1fc8-4815-89bb-3660da92429f 
TID: [-1234] [] [2019-10-15 09:13:54,775] DEBUG {org.wso2.carbon.identity.application.authentication.framework.services.PostAuthenticationMgtService} -  PostAuthenticatedSubjectIdentifierHandler is enabled. Hence executing for context : a87394cd-1fc8-4815-89bb-3660da92429f 
TID: [-1234] [] [2019-10-15 09:13:54,775] DEBUG {org.wso2.carbon.identity.application.authentication.framework.services.PostAuthenticationMgtService} -  Post authentication handler PostAuthenticatedSubjectIdentifierHandler returned with status : SUCCESS_COMPLETED for context identifier : a87394cd-1fc8-4815-89bb-3660da92429f 
TID: [-1234] [] [2019-10-15 09:13:54,775] DEBUG {org.wso2.carbon.identity.application.authentication.framework.services.PostAuthenticationMgtService} -  Post authentication handler PostAuthenticatedSubjectIdentifierHandler completed execution for session context : a87394cd-1fc8-4815-89bb-3660da92429f 
TID: [-1234] [] [2019-10-15 09:13:54,775] DEBUG {org.wso2.carbon.identity.application.authentication.framework.services.PostAuthenticationMgtService} -  MissingClaimPostAuthnHandler is enabled. Hence executing for context : a87394cd-1fc8-4815-89bb-3660da92429f 
TID: [-1234] [] [2019-10-15 09:13:54,775] DEBUG {org.wso2.carbon.identity.application.authentication.framework.handler.request.impl.PostAuthnMissingClaimHandler} -  Post authentication handling for missing claims started 
TID: [-1234] [] [2019-10-15 09:13:54,776] DEBUG {org.wso2.carbon.identity.application.authentication.framework.handler.request.impl.PostAuthnMissingClaimHandler} -  Mandatory claims missing for the application : http://wso2.org/claims/phoneNumbers, 
TID: [-1234] [] [2019-10-15 09:13:54,776] DEBUG {org.wso2.carbon.identity.claim.metadata.mgt.dao.CacheBackedLocalClaimDAO} -  Cache hit for local claim list for tenant: -1234 
TID: [-1234] [] [2019-10-15 09:13:54,776] DEBUG {org.wso2.carbon.identity.application.authentication.framework.handler.request.impl.PostAuthnMissingClaimHandler} -  Redirecting to outside to pick mandatory claims 
TID: [-1234] [] [2019-10-15 09:13:54,776] DEBUG {org.wso2.carbon.identity.application.authentication.framework.services.PostAuthenticationMgtService} -  Post authentication handler MissingClaimPostAuthnHandler returned with status : INCOMPLETE for context identifier : a87394cd-1fc8-4815-89bb-3660da92429f 
TID: [-1234] [] [2019-10-15 09:13:54,776] DEBUG {org.wso2.carbon.identity.application.authentication.framework.services.PostAuthenticationMgtService} -  Post authentication handler MissingClaimPostAuthnHandler is not completed yet. Hence returning for context : a87394cd-1fc8-4815-89bb-3660da92429f 
TID: [-1234] [] [2019-10-15 09:13:54,777] DEBUG {org.wso2.carbon.identity.application.authentication.framework.handler.request.impl.DefaultRequestCoordinator} -  Context id: a87394cd-1fc8-4815-89bb-3660da92429f left the thread with id: 137 
TID: [-1234] [] [2019-10-15 09:13:54,779] DEBUG {org.wso2.carbon.caching.impl.CacheImpl} -  Notification event trigger for cache entry update : class org.wso2.carbon.caching.impl.clustering.ClusterCacheInvalidationRequestSender 
TID: [-1234] [] [2019-10-15 09:13:54,779] DEBUG {org.wso2.carbon.identity.application.authentication.framework.cache.AuthenticationContextCache} -  Authentication context is stored with details [ Context Id : a87394cd-1fc8-4815-89bb-3660da92429f, Cache type : AuthenticationContextCache, Operation : STORE ] 
TID: [-1234] [] [2019-10-15 09:13:54,784] DEBUG {org.wso2.carbon.identity.application.authentication.framework.handler.request.impl.DefaultRequestCoordinator} -  Context with id: a87394cd-1fc8-4815-89bb-3660da92429f added to the cache. 
TID: [-1234] [] [2019-10-15 09:16:51,429] DEBUG {org.wso2.carbon.identity.auth.service.handler.HandlerManager} -  Created singleton instance for org.wso2.carbon.identity.auth.service.handler.HandlerManager 
TID: [-1234] [] [2019-10-15 09:16:51,429] DEBUG {org.wso2.carbon.identity.auth.service.handler.HandlerManager} -  Get first priority handler for the given handler list. 
TID: [-1234] [] [2019-10-15 09:16:51,430] DEBUG {org.wso2.carbon.identity.auth.service.handler.HandlerManager} -  Get first priority handler : DefaultAuthenticationManager(org.wso2.carbon.identity.auth.service.AuthenticationManager) 
TID: [-1234] [] [2019-10-15 09:16:51,432] DEBUG {org.wso2.carbon.identity.application.authenticator.oidc.OpenIDConnectAuthenticator} -  Inside OpenIDConnectAuthenticator.getContextIdentifier() 
TID: [-1234] [] [2019-10-15 09:16:51,433] DEBUG {org.wso2.carbon.identity.application.authenticator.oidc.OpenIDConnectAuthenticator} -  Inside OpenIDConnectAuthenticator.getContextIdentifier() 
TID: [-1234] [] [2019-10-15 09:16:51,433] DEBUG {org.wso2.carbon.identity.application.authentication.framework.cache.AuthenticationContextCache} -  Found a valid AuthenticationContextCacheEntry corresponding to the session data key : a87394cd-1fc8-4815-89bb-3660da92429f from the cache.  
TID: [-1234] [] [2019-10-15 09:16:51,434] DEBUG {org.wso2.carbon.identity.application.authentication.framework.handler.request.impl.DefaultRequestCoordinator} -  Context id: a87394cd-1fc8-4815-89bb-3660da92429f is active in the thread with id: 139 
TID: [-1234] [] [2019-10-15 09:16:51,434] DEBUG {org.wso2.carbon.identity.application.authentication.framework.handler.request.impl.DefaultAuthenticationRequestHandler} -  In authentication flow 
TID: [-1234] [] [2019-10-15 09:16:51,434] DEBUG {org.wso2.carbon.identity.application.authentication.framework.handler.sequence.impl.GraphBasedSequenceHandler} -  Executing the Step Based Authentication... 
TID: [-1234] [] [2019-10-15 09:16:51,435] DEBUG {org.wso2.carbon.identity.application.authentication.framework.handler.sequence.impl.GraphBasedSequenceHandler} -  Authentication Graph not defined for the application. Performing Step based authentication. Service Provider :TestService 
TID: [-1234] [] [2019-10-15 09:16:51,435] DEBUG {org.wso2.carbon.identity.application.authentication.framework.handler.sequence.impl.DefaultStepBasedSequenceHandler} -  Executing the Step Based Authentication... 
TID: [-1234] [] [2019-10-15 09:16:51,435] DEBUG {org.wso2.carbon.identity.application.authentication.framework.handler.request.impl.DefaultAuthenticationRequestHandler} -  Handling post authentication 
TID: [-1234] [] [2019-10-15 09:16:51,435] DEBUG {org.wso2.carbon.identity.application.authentication.framework.services.PostAuthenticationMgtService} -  Executing Post Authentication Management Service for context a87394cd-1fc8-4815-89bb-3660da92429f 
TID: [-1234] [] [2019-10-15 09:16:51,436] DEBUG {org.wso2.carbon.identity.application.authentication.framework.services.PostAuthenticationMgtService} -  Starting from current post handler index 5 for context : a87394cd-1fc8-4815-89bb-3660da92429f 
TID: [-1234] [] [2019-10-15 09:16:51,436] DEBUG {org.wso2.carbon.identity.application.authentication.framework.handler.request.impl.DefaultRequestCoordinator} -  Error occurred while evaluating post authentication 
org.wso2.carbon.identity.application.authentication.framework.exception.PostAuthenticationFailedException: Post authentication sequence tracking cookie not found in request with context id : a87394cd-1fc8-4815-89bb-3660da92429f
    at org.wso2.carbon.identity.application.authentication.framework.services.PostAuthenticationMgtService.validatePASTRCookie(PostAuthenticationMgtService.java:207)
    at org.wso2.carbon.identity.application.authentication.framework.services.PostAuthenticationMgtService.handlePostAuthentication(PostAuthenticationMgtService.java:76)
    at org.wso2.carbon.identity.application.authentication.framework.handler.request.impl.DefaultAuthenticationRequestHandler.handlePostAuthentication(DefaultAuthenticationRequestHandler.java:165)
    at org.wso2.carbon.identity.application.authentication.framework.handler.request.impl.DefaultAuthenticationRequestHandler.handle(DefaultAuthenticationRequestHandler.java:142)
    at org.wso2.carbon.identity.application.authentication.framework.handler.request.impl.DefaultRequestCoordinator.handle(DefaultRequestCoordinator.java:239)
    at org.wso2.carbon.identity.application.authentication.framework.servlet.CommonAuthenticationServlet.doPost(CommonAuthenticationServlet.java:53)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [WSO2 Identity Server SAML2 Response Issuer verification failed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50569438/wso2-identity-server-saml2-response-issuer-verification-failed)

Comment: Thank yout, but it still doesn't work.